# Is "there has got to be" grammatical?

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-construction, sentence-structure

> There **has got to be** the establishment of a universal auxiliary language.

Does the verb *got* add more to the context or is it there just for emphasis? Is it even grammatical?

Using Google-Ngrams I found a few similar versions as follow: [there has * to be](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=there%20has%20*%20to%20be&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Cthere%20has%20%2A%20to%20be%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bthere%20has%20come%20to%20be%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bthere%20has%20seemed%20to%20be%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bthere%20has%20got%20to%20be%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bthere%20has%20ceased%20to%20be%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bthere%20has%20yet%20to%20be%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bthere%20has%20appeared%20to%20be%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bthere%20has%20had%20to%20be%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bthere%20has%20tended%20to%20be%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bthere%20has%20continued%20to%20be%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bthere%20has%20proved%20to%20be%3B%2Cc0#t2%3B%2Cthere%20has%20*%20to%20be%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bthere%20has%20come%20to%20be%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bthere%20has%20seemed%20to%20be%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bthere%20has%20got%20to%20be%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bthere%20has%20ceased%20to%20be%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bthere%20has%20yet%20to%20be%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bthere%20has%20appeared%20to%20be%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bthere%20has%20had%20to%20be%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bthere%20has%20tended%20to%20be%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bthere%20has%20continued%20to%20be%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bthere%20has%20proved%20to%20be%3B%2Cc0). For example;

1. For many from the North, however, it has seemed difficult and there **has seemed to be** a problem.
2. There **has come to be** a convolution between this become enmeshed concept of marriage as it exists in the sacred and how it exists in the secular.
3. Most of the time since I have been here, there **has appeared to be** considerable feeling in the minds of a few.
4. There **has had to be** some negotiation, obviously, but I think we provided what our soldiers need and what our country needs.

In general, I wanna know if *'have/has'+past-participle+'to be'* is grammatical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That "got" is just omissible.

See [HAVE | meaning in the Cambridge English Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/have?q=have%20got):

> have
>
> modal verb
>
> have (got) to do sth

​And see [Have got to and have to - English Grammar Today - Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/have-got-to-and-have-to):

> *Have got to* and *have to* mean the same. *Have got to* is more informal. We use *have (got) to* here to refer to both verbs.